# Solution to truncated renewal function

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, stochastic-integrals

Let's begin with some theory on the renewal process.

In a renewal process $N(t)$, let $t$ denote the interarrival time, and $f(t)$ and $F(t)$ denote the PDF and CDF respectively. Let $M(t)=E[N(t)]$, and $M(t)$ is known to be the `renewal function`, which satisfies the following `renewal equation`:

\begin{equation}
M(t)=F(t)+\int_0^tM(t-x)dF(x)             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{equation}

Taking Laplace transform on both sides of equation (1) we have (we use a tilde to indicate Laplace transform)

$$\tilde{M}(s)=\tilde{F}(s)+\tilde{M}(s)\tilde{f}(s)$$

Note that the $\int_0^tM(t-x)dF(x)$ part is actually the convolution of $M(t)$ and $f(t)$, so the Laplace transform of this term is $\tilde{M}(s)\tilde{f}(s)$.
Then $$\tilde{M}(s) = \frac{\tilde{F}(s)}{1-\tilde{f}(s)}$$

At last we can calculate $M(t)$ by taking the inverse Laplace transform of $\tilde{M}(s)$.

In some special cases, we have known in advance that $M(t)=0$ when $t<\tau$, then (1) becomes

\begin{equation}
M(t)=\mathbf 1_{t>\tau} (F(t)+\int_0^tM(t-x)dF(x))             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{equation}

So how to derive a solution for $\tilde{M}(s)$ by still applying Laplace on both sides of (2)? I have tried this by myself, but I don't how to deal with the convolution term $\int_0^tM(t-x)dF(x)$.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Did Would you please give me a help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N(t)=M(t+\tau)$ and $G(t)=F(t+\tau)$ then, for every nonnegative $t$, $$N(t)=G(t)+\int_0^tN(t-x)\,\mathrm dF(x)$$ hence $$\tilde{N}(s)=\frac{\tilde{G}(s)}{1-\tilde{f}(s)}.$$

Comment: Why the integral upper limit $t$  does not change to $t+\tau$?

Comment: Because $M(s)=0$ for every $s\lt\tau$ hence, for every $x\gt t$, $t+\tau-x\lt\tau$ implies $N(t-x)=M(t+\tau-x)=0$.